# Can't create a new user on a Kinvey.com app

Tags: user-registration, error-code, kinvey

I'm trying to create a new user on kinvey.com using iOS, and it succeeds (at least it shows up in the console) but I also get an error: Kinvey Ertror Code = 406, "Device token is empty".

Can someone please explain what that means, and how to get around it?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: This sounds like it's a question for Kinvey directly at their support forum - https://support.kinvey.com/

Answer (score 0):

We have a thread on the Kinvey forums that has been set up to address this issue.   We are tracking it over here:  https://support.kinvey.com/discussions/topics/12000000705/page/last/#post_12000002420

We have patched this issue and are awaiting user feedback of the new SDK.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem..
I was using kinvey 1.40.3  ->  did an update:  "pod update" in the terminal to 1.40.4

since then it is working for me

Peter